# Query only returning ID and URL of workItems list not returning title

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm working with VSO (Visual Studio Online API), I am using this query:

```
{
"name": "All Workitems",
"wiql": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
}
```

Well I am expecting a list of Work Items with ID Title and its state but in response I'm only getting its ID and URL. What query should I use?

Response:

```
{
    "queryType": "flat",
    "queryResultType": "workItem",
    "asOf": "2015-04-18T05:23:05.353Z",
    "columns": [
        {
            "referenceName": "System.Id",
            "name": "ID",
            "url": "https://sami1212.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields/System.Id"
        },
        {
            "referenceName": "System.Title",
            "name": "Title",
            "url": "https://sami1212.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields/System.Title"
        },
        {
            "referenceName": "System.State",
            "name": "State",
            "url": "https://sami1212.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields/System.State"
        }
    ],
    "sortColumns": [
        {
            "field": {
                "referenceName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority",
                "name": "Priority",
                "url": "https://sami1212.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority"
            },
            "descending": false
        },
        {
            "field": {
                "referenceName": "System.CreatedDate",
                "name": "Created Date",
                "url": "https://sami1212.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields/System.CreatedDate"
            },
            "descending": true
        }
    ],
    "workItems": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "url": "https://sami1212.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/7"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "url": "https://sami1212.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/6"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "url": "https://sami1212.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/5"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "url": "https://sami1212.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/4"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "url": "https://sami1212.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/3"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "url": "https://sami1212.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/2"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "url": "https://sami1212.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem, 
We can simply get a list of all webItems using ID based WorkItems, we will concat all the ids into 'ids' query param, which will return list of all selected ids. e.g.

https://sami1212.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=1,2,3,4,5&api-version=1.0

Answer (score 1):

`select [system.id] from workitems`

and then when I got the result, I have extracted all the id's from the body -> field -> {id, url} [list]

with the list of Id's as specified I've sent the list of id's to list workitems endpoint

i.e. `/workitems?ids=1,2, ...` and you should be getting the result for all the work items with all the fields..

interesting thing is we can also pass where in (ids, ids2 ..) clause while querying for all the workitems. Pass in `fields` query parameter to filter the fields